# How to get list of facebook contacts from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, contacts

I'm writing a Ruby on Rails (3.1) app where a user can send emails from a form in the app as part of the workflow. At the moment the email field is just an html input where the user can type/paste in an email address. What I would like to do is, with the users permission, give them the option of a selector of their facebook contacts.

Comment: Should be easy to do, just follow the guide posted below; however, you won't be able to get the user's friends' emails—Facebook doesn't allow you to do that because it could allow spamming!

Comment: The user's friends email is what I would need so that the user can easily send emails to their friends from my app. Though perhaps it would do just to send a facebook message instead of an email.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you can't do that. I'm working with a similar situation and we prompt the user to enter their friends' emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Facebook API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Rails specific: [follow this guide](http://dikdiktasdiklaksana.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/facebook-app-requests-dialog/).